# Print a javafx tableview entire contents not just screenshot of current page

Tags: javafx

I tried printing a table using javafx print api. The problem is my table has too many columns to fit the screen so there is a horizontal scrollbar in the table and when i tried printing it, the table is saved as a snapshot of current window but i want to print all of the data in the table and not as a screenshot if possible.
All i want is to print all of the data of table i.e print table without horizontal scroll. I dont care whether it is printed as  screenshot or text but the print page should contain all columns of table.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918959/javafx-print-tableview-on-multiple-pages/37118619#37118619) may help. I ran into this problem a while back. Hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use JasperReports to print your data of tableView https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%205.6.0/