# Printing ObservableList As Table On A4 Page

Tags: javafx, printing

**What is the easiest way to print data on multiple pages in Java FX?**

I have tried **Jasper Report** too but it takes time to show the report and its result is not fast. JavaFX's node print is extremely complex, **Printing single page is easy, but** data that spans multiple pages is difficult to manage and a beginner student like me can't easily understand it unless it gets the help of experts.

So My problem is that:
I have the data in the form of an observable list that I can also display in the table. **I want to print this data in table style on A4 page size** in such a way that **if the data exceeds the page size it will print it on another page**. If any of you specialists can guide me in this matter, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You could build your own cells using a String. Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918959/javafx-print-tableview-on-multiple-pages).

Comment: @Safdar Ali This is not easy here is a link to a similar question Not a great solution but worth a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918959/javafx-print-tableview-on-multiple-pages?noredirect=1&lq=1